# PHP showing up as plain text

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple form and php file. When I click submit it just pulls up a plain text file with the contents of resources.php. Why would this be happening?

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="resources.php" method='POST'>

        <input type="text"  placeholder="Name" name="name"><br>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Organization" name="organization"><br>
        <input type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email"><br>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Street Address" name="streetaddress"><br>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Phone Number" name="phonenumber"><br>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="What is three plus four?" name="human"><br>

        <input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the resources.php file...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php

    echo '<pre>'.$_POST.'<pre>';

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you're seeing the PHP code *on the client* that means your web server isn't processing the code.  You would likely need to re-install and/or re-configure PHP on your server.

Comment: Your server isn't configured to execute PHP, or you've saved your files as .html, which aren't executed as PHP either. Plus, `echo $_POST` will NOT work. you'll just get the literal word `Array` as output.

Comment: Does your webserver recognizing and executing PHP files?  If you're using Apache, for instance, you'll need to have a line like `AddType x-httpd-php .php ` somewhere in your conf and the libphp.so file will need to be available as a module.

Comment: @MarcB `print_r($_POST)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are possible answers to your problem:

1. WEB server is not processing your PHP code correctly because php is not installed or misconfigured.
2. You're not using the web server at all. Make sure to load your pages from localhost (or whatever your server is) and not from the file itself
   ex:  localhost/path/to/index.html
   and not c://program files...

Comment: Does resources.php need to be executable?