# php code is being commented out in browser as html comments on ChaletOS

Tags: php

I am running a simple php echo but it is not working. My code:-

```
<?php 
echo "hello world!!";
?>
```

When I inspected it, my php code is being commented. How can I resolve my Problem?

Comment: Please add full script where you have this php code or is this a full script?

Comment: It is a fulll script only for testing.

Comment: What server are you using to execute PHP?

Comment: I dont think its the case but just for the safety I am asking :) are you saving the file with `.php` extension or you are using `.html`

Comment: Apache2 Server for php

Comment: Saving with .php

Comment: Does a plain HTML document or image work? Did you change the `php.ini` file? What other files are on the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP showing up as plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260476/php-showing-up-as-plain-text)

Comment: How can I fix errors Aloso and Chris

Comment: If you aren't comfortable with configuring a Web server I suggest you use a preconfigured one, like wamp/xamp/etc